ObjectNotExecutableError trying to execute SQL on remote MySQL Server with sqlalchemy.create_engine
I have got a remote access to a MySQLServer server and able to execute the SQL correctly using workbench getting desired results. However when I execute the same SQL from the same machine using sqlalchemy I get an error of:
ObjectNotExecutableError    

Here is my code:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_user = os.environ['USER']
db_password = os.environ['PWD']
db_host = os.environ['HOST']
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}")

with engine.connect() as con:

  rs = con.execute('SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;')
  for row in rs:
    print(row)

Any ideas?

from sqlalchemy import text, then con.execute(text('SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;'))

@python_user thanks. it worked. Feel free to add it as an answer and I will be glad to accpet. You can probably also solve my other problem with SQLAgent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78338498/connectionreseterror-while-running-sqlagent-on-remote-mysql-server

glad to have helped, added it, also seems you have found a solution for that, I will try to see if I can replicate it

You have to use sqlalchemy.text like so con.execute(text("SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;"))
Complete Code
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

db_user = os.environ["USER"]
db_password = os.environ["PWD"]
db_host = os.environ["HOST"]
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}")

with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(text("SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata;"))
    for row in rs:
        print(row)

