ConnectionResetError while running SQLAgent on remote MySQL Server
I have got remote access to a MySQLServer and able to exeucte SQL statements getting desired results from my windows laptop using workbench. However when I run a SQLAgent with my english like query, after a few steps I get an error of:
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Here is my code:
from langchain import SQLDatabase
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI, AzureOpenAI
db_user = os.environ['USER']
db_password = os.environ['PWD']
db_host = os.environ['HOST']
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}/<my schema>")

aoi = AzureChatOpenAI(temperature=0,
                deployment_name = os.environ['AZURE_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'],
                azure_endpoint = os.environ['AZURE_ENDPOINT'],
                api_version = "2023-06-01-preview")

from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db,llm=aoi)

from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent

agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
    llm=aoi,
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True,
)

agent_executor.invoke({"input" : "<my english query>"})

SQLAgent seems to successfully perform initial actions e.g. sql_db_list_tables listing all the tables correctly. It also correctly identifies the table to be queried for my specified query. It prints Action sql_db_schema with this correctly identified table as the Action Input after which I get this exception.
Any ideas?

Not sure whether it was some transient error but it had been failing consistently with the sam error for the past 3 days. Now it is working! Can't think of any changes...
